# When streaming with Icecast and Liquidsoap the sound keep rewinding

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, icecast, liquidsoap

when I stream with Liquidsoap and Icecast the stream keep playing the same part over and over, with a rewind sound...

This is the stream: http://radio.oursound.com.br:8000/oursoundradio

I was unable to find anything about it, this is my liq script

```
source = input.http("http://LINK_TO_MP3.mp3",buffer=10.0, max=20.0,logfile="/tmp/001.log")
source = mksafe(source)
output.icecast(%vorbis,host="localhost",password="password",mount="oursoundradio", source)
```

I am using vorbis, because when I use MP3, I keep getting this error

```
strange error flushing buffer ...
strange error flushing buffer ...
strange error flushing buffer ...
strange error flushing buffer ...
```

But this is for another day, what I need help is with the  streaming rewinding, I am completely new to Liquidsoap and Icecast...

But already read all the documentation, and found nothing...

Thanks for the help...

Comment: I am using ubuntu btw

Comment: The log keeps going to 
`0.066549 882000` and truncating and repeating, maybe the script is running again, but how to make it wait the music play to the end before re-running??

Comment: Just FYI, The "Strange error flushing buffer...." is actually an error thrown by the mp3 encoder "lame". Im not sure what causes this bu if I remember correctly it could be related to using a too low bitrate. In any event it is not a critical error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input.http` is meant to be used for radio-style HTTP streams that never really end.  Liquidsoap is treating it as such, getting disconnected when the file is fully downloaded, and is likely looping a buffer.  There shouldn't be a "rewind" sound... you're probably hearing a blip of an MP3 artifact.  Your station is down right now, or I'd give it a listen to check.

You should use [`single`](http://liquidsoap.fm/doc-1.2.0/reference.html#single) instead.  Untested, but try something like this:

```
source = once(single("http://example.com/file.mp3"))
```

Of course in practice, you probably actually want [`playlist`](http://liquidsoap.fm/doc-1.2.0/reference.html#playlist).

Comment: I started the radio again, I will look on what you said, that really makes sense...
What i need to accomplish is a radio which receives a new url from a JSON on the webservice part, and play it... I think this single can do that for me

Comment: Hahahahahahah, this is using once and single: http://radio.oursound.com.br:8000/oursoundradio3

Thanks!!!

Comment: It worked perfectly!!! Now its time to find out how to dinamically load a new mp3 url from a JSON received from a webservice everytime the current mp3 ends :)

Comment: @TLPNull Better to have your web service send playlists and load those instead.  Less code to write in Liquidsoap (which is always easier), and it allows Liquidsoap to buffer the next tracks.

Comment: U mean a m3u file?? I am trying to do this, generating an m3u file on an fixed link, with authentication and so on, I hope this works, thanks for the tip, if you have any other I will be happy to receive

Comment: @TLPNull Yes, an M3U would work just fine.  No need for it to be an actual file... just output the M3U contents with the correct `Content-Type` header and Liquidsoap should be able to figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue and I solved by (logged as `root`):

`apt install --reinstall icecast2`